# How does this sequence of iterated $\sin^2$ converge and what's the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was riding my bike yesterday and thinking about the following expression:

Suppose $$S_3 = \sin^2(\frac\pi2) + \sin^2(\sin^2(\frac\pi2)) + \sin^2(\sin^2(\sin^2(\frac\pi2)))$$ which serves to define an $$S_n$$ that has $n$ of these terms, the last of which being $n$ successive applications of $\sin^2$.

Now, you will appreciate that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{S_n}$$ goes "somewhere". I have no idea how to calculate it, and what type of maths would describe its calculation. All I know is that it seems to drift close to the religious rational number $\frac73$ - although as someone pointed out, not quite that number.

During the bike ride I was actually interested in building an expression $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(S_n-C)^{F(n)}$ and see if it combines $e$ and $\pi$ in a new expression. Note that for instance $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2}} = e$$ so even the quick "convergence" of $S_n$ can bloom open to something interesting when other operators are involved.

Now, sitting at my desk I realise that I don't even know where to start with that original idea, as I don't even know how to compute the limit.

Can anyone point me in a direction, does this iteration of $\sin^2$ converge? How does one prove it? Are there more things I could read about sine hyperoperators like these?

I'm probably overlooking something basic - I'm not that knowledgable in maths. Thanks for any hints!

Comment: A good estimate of the sum is $2.3284669142910280888416748949659$. You don't seem to have computed a lot. The series converges very fast, as the successive terms are obtained by squaring.

Comment: Calculated 5 terms, like you :)

Comment: I edited the question a little based on this discussion, thanks for pointing out there's no religion involving 7/3.

Comment: $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2}=e.$

Comment: Ah oops, of course. Sorry, I'll edit that, my point stays the same ("mastering the convergance"). thx again

Comment: In what way is this ([tag:hyperoperation]) and not simply an [iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) with the ([tag:sequences-and-series]) tag instead?

Comment: It has nothing to do with hyperoperations. I'm gonna change tags.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\le1$, $\sin^2(x)\le x\sin(1)\le1$ and the series is bounded by a converging geometric series of common ratio $\sin(1)$.

---

Below a plot of the first partial sums.

[image]

Comment: Is there then a nice expression for the limit?

Comment: @buddhabrot: no. (Unless Ramanujan worked on that.)

Comment: That's incredibly disappointing. I will keep hunting based on your common ratio hint.

Comment: @buddhabrot: this is a gross upper bound, it will lead you nowhere. This problem is intractable.

Comment: Yes I realise but even this simple ingredient on breaking the recursion has got me thinking.
Still, I don't feel like accepting the answer, it avoids the meat, and want to enable other viewpoints that get closer. I have since changed it to "How does it converge".

Comment: @buddhabrot: it obviously has quadratic convergence. And is intractable.

Comment: I don’t know what untractable or intractable means in terms of mathematics. I will attempt imagining a physical system that ends up related to this hyperoperator to prove the meaning of the limit is tangible. My intuition says there is a simple expression. Without it, I will not be able to put it in a power function to see how the convergence behaves under powers.

Comment: I should have focused on sin instead of sin^2, which converges slower

Comment: Just as an observation, if you draw the curve of y=sin^2(x) and also draw a curve of x=sin^2(y), and focus on the region in (0,1) for x and y, this problem is related to bouncing off the x/y axises towards the curves. There is a solution hidden there.